# Change input field to disabled or enable depending on select dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have an input field be enabled or disabled depending on the choice of the drop down.

Code fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/cr7dW/

```
$('#getHoldStatus').change(function()
                    {
                        var selected_item = $(this).val()
                        if(selected_item == "On Hold until Candidate Available"){
                            $('#datepicker').val("").removeClass('hidden');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#datepicker').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
                        }
                    }
                    );
```

In this example you will see three date fields what will use jquery datepicker

The idea is that when the page first loads that the input fields of: Hold start date and Hold end Date will be either: Not displayed or disabled.

If "On Hold until Candidate Available" is selected then Both Hold start date and hold end date are activate/visible. If "on hold until position available" is selected then Only Hold start date is active/visible.

I found a script that works but when I try it on my page its not working.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at the script and there are a couple of things you want to change.

1) Instead of display:none in css change to visibility:hidden
2) When javascript returns a selected_item it returns the value of the dropdown not the text so you want to check if(selected_item=="3") or whatever number you require.

This should sort out the issue.

Comment: Well maybe a bit too soon.. that did it in the jsFiddle but it still is having issues when I adjust the code on my page. One thing I did was to use the .invisible class from bootstrap. It hides the input field nicely but after changing the code over so that .invisible is being used, it's not working from the drop down.  The fiddle should be updated with the changes and it works on there. Just not in the acutal code.

Comment: Glad I could Hlpe, as suggested though can you provide your actual code.

Comment: Might be hard to do, the code is running on ColdFusion on the back end. I'm more than happy to help posting it any other way possible. I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> I found a script that works but when I try it on my page its not
>   working.

If the script is working on jsFiddle and not on your site there could be following things to check.

1. If jQuery is added successfully.
2. You have put the code in document.ready function.

**Edit: ** based on comment by OP

In change event you are comparing value using val() with the text which you should compare  with value instead of text.

*Change*

```
if(selected_item == "On Hold until Candidate Available"){
```

*To*

```
if(selected_item == "3"){
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working and remove the extra code and controls to make it simple?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/EdLax/1/ - Updated fiddle. The idea is that, if I select: NONE - Then both Hold Start Date and Hold End Date are NOT active. SCD is active - If I select On Hold until candidate Available then All 3 Dates Hold Start, Hold End and SCD are active. IF I select On hold until position available then only Hold Start and SCD are active.  Thanks

Comment: Just got a chance to try document.ready. This was the final step. Thanks to everyone for the help. Now, on to the next issue. I'm sure I'll be back soon!